# Why this code compile but not running

Tags: c, pointers, puts

Why this code compile but not running?

```
int main() {
     char *s;

     scanf("%15s", s);
     puts(s);
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry to have to inform you that compiling fine and then not running correctly is normal behaviour.

Comment: the answers answer precisely as to what is wrong but I do feel that its missing the return statement

Comment: @BP you do not need a return statement in `main` according to the C11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

Because `s` is an uninitialized pointer, you cannot store data there (since there "is no there there").

Try:

```
char s[32];
```

instead, that gives you 32 characters' worth of room into which `scanf()` can write.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide memory for `scanf(...)`  The `char *s` is only a pointer to some memory, but not he memory itself.  You can either `malloc(...)` the memory and have `s` point to it, or allocate it locally on the stack by `char s[16]`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, provide a proper buffer to the `scanf` call.  For example, instead of `char *s` which is simply an uninitialized pointer, try `char s[128]`.